# Replace double hyphens in page title with single hyphen

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have page titles like this:

```
$pageTitle = "<title>site - {$cat} - {$q} - {$prod} - {$prodName}</title>";
$pageTitle = str_replace(' - - ', ' - ', $pageTitle);    
echo $pageTitle;
```

Sometimes this echos page titles like this:

```
<title>site - SportingGoods - Airbed -  - SportingGoods</title>
```

When this happens and one of the vars is empty I want to remove the empty the double hyphen with a single one. I thought something like str_replace would work here but it doesn't.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just realised this title has SportingGoods in it twice but that is another issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one is empty you'll have two spaces (not one) between the hyphens:

```
$pageTitle = str_replace(' -  - ', ' - ', $pageTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Double space! Copy & paste is your friend!
$pageTitle = str_replace(' -  - ', ' - ', $pageTitle);
```

To solve the complete problem use this:

```
$titleParts = array($cat, $q, $prod, $prodName);
$titleParts = array_unique($titleParts);

$pageTitle  = implode(' - ', $titleParts);
$pageTitle  = str_replace(' -  - ', ' - ', $pageTitle);
```